# Genitive ending of proper nouns ending in "s" or "z"

Tags: genitive

> Lars has a book.
>   Fritz has a house.

How do I show possession using the genitive ending "s" for a proper noun that ends in an "s" or "z"?

> Das ist Lars(?) Buch.
>   Das ist Fritz(?) Haus.

Comment: I added a second example, extending the question to include "z".

Comment: Why the close vote? This is a non-trivial question that would be answered differently in former and modern times.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As presumed in the question the "normal" genitive-"s" would look strange (Larss Buch, Fritzs Haus). So the [official rules (§ 96.1)](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/Interpunktion/pgf96-97.html) and also [rule 16 at Duden Sprachwissen](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/apostroph#K16) say, that the genitive-"s" is omitted and an apostroph is used to show the omission:

> Das ist Lars' Buch.
> Das ist Fritz' Haus.

In northern Germany, there is/was the ending "-ens" used in colloquial speech for masculine names, so it would read:

> Das ist Larsens Buch.
> Das ist Fritzens Haus.

But this ending is very old-fashioned.

Note that the apostrophe has no correlation with the genitive-"'s" used in English. As mentioned it only denotes the omission of letters.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57844/discussion-on-answer-by-iqv-genitive-ending-of-proper-nouns-ending-in-s-or-z).